# Javascript Recursive Function get key and value

Tags: javascript

Working with Recursive function, I want to return an object with key, value. But I am returning an array with keys and values inside.

```
 let path = (myObj: any) => {
          if (myObj) {
            const isObject = (val: any) =>
              typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val)
            //Path Name
            const addDelimiter = (a: any, b: any) => (a ? `${a}.schema.${b}` : b)
            const paths = (obj = {}, head = '') => {
              return Object.entries(obj || {}).reduce(
                (product, [key, value]: any) => {
                  let fullPath = addDelimiter(head, key)
                  if (isObject(value)) {
                    return product.concat(paths(value, fullPath))
                  } else {
                    )
                    return product.concat({ [fullPath]: value })
                  }
                },
                []
              )
            }
```

returns

```
0: {name.schema.data: "lollololol"}
1: {name.schema.info: "John"}
```

I want outcome:

```
{
name.schema.data: "lollololol"
name.schema.info: "John"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an array, then don't start your reducer with an array, but with a plain object, and merge using `Object.assign` instead of `.concat`:

```
  return Object.entries(obj || {}).reduce(
    (product, [key, value]: any) => {
      let fullPath = addDelimiter(head, key)
      if (isObject(value)) {
        // Merge objects with `.assign`, not `.concat`:
        return Object.assign(product, paths(value, fullPath));
      } else {
        return Object.assign(product, { [fullPath]: value });
      }
    },
    {} // <-- plain object instead of array
  )
```

Alternatively, you can also use object literal spread syntax:

```
      if (isObject(value)) {
        return { ...product, ...paths(value, fullPath) };
      } else {
        return { ...product, ...{ [fullPath]: value } };
      }
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for